# Should My ERC721 Show In A Wallet?

Tags: wallets, erc-721

We've created and deployed a contract to mint and issue an ERC721 token. I've gone to our admin page in our dapp and "sent" 3 of them to my personal address.

When I check my address in etherscan I see the 3 listed in my erc721 token txns. When I check for those token id's in truffle console looking at the live network they return my address.

So that all seems good to go. Should I be surprised that the tokens don't show up in a coinbase wallet or enjin wallet?

I'm wondering if there's a wallet that will show them, or maybe if there's something wrong with the contract I deployed and I didn't actually mint a fully compliant 721.

Thanks for any ideas.
Kevin

Answer (score 4):

Not many crypto wallets do support the ERC721 Standard out there,
[TrustWallet](https://trustwallet.com/) is probably one of the few that has implemented the standard for some time now.

You should definitely try [TrustWallet](https://trustwallet.com/), a simple, fast and fully decentralized wallet.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your token contract implements the correct interface, it should be valid ERC721. You can find the interface for example here: http://erc721.org/

The next issues is whether a wallet knows how to display ERC721 tokens. I believe not many wallets currently support ERC721, but it looks like Enjin wallet should.

So I suggest you double-check your token contract code and after that make sure you're using the right addresses. Probably your minting contract is a different contract from the token contract (or is it?) so remember to use the right address.